# Xamarin Web Authenticator does not persist when placing app on foreground

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm currently building a Xamarin app that uses WebAuthenticator to handle all authentication purposes. After calling AuthenticateAsync, the client is taken to an auth provider to login using their credentials. However, their system uses something called DUO, an app for different two-factor authentication methods. So when they use this it opens another app and puts the original client in the foreground. The problem arises right when the client is redirected back to the app. The access token is never passed. I also noticed this same issue when the client opens a different app. Is there a way to persist the authURI when it's put in foreground?

This is the current implementation for the call to the AuthenticateAsync

```
 try
        {
            var authResult = await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
            {
                var authUrl = BuildAuthUrl();
                var redirect = new Uri(Redirect);
                return await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(url: BuildAuthUrl(), callbackUrl: new Uri(Redirect));
            });
            string code = authResult.Properties["code"];
            var token = await GetToken(code);
```

Comment: Which platform do you run this app?  UWP, iOS, Andriod?

Comment: Currently it's for Android and IOS

Comment: May be you could try Microsoft Authentication Library instead, it  supports authentication for different kinds of modern application architectures. For more information, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview

Comment: @AdrainZhu Thank you, I'll try this!

Comment: Hope that would work